# How to use an argument from a parent function inside of an eventListener?

Tags: javascript

Basically, this function opens a modal when the user either wants to add a printer or edit the current printer. The printers are laid out in a table with their various traits.

The row parameter of the openmodal function is the row where the event was fired from. However, when I try to access this row inside of my `edit` eventListener, which is fired when the person chooses to edit a row, it only ever accesses the first row that was edited.

How can I use the correct row in my eventListener?

```
function openmodal(option, row) {
    backdropModal.style.display = "block";
    modal.style.display = "block";
    if (option === 'add-new') {
        edit.style.display = 'none';
    }
    edit.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        var editedPrinter = new Printer(
            document.getElementById('post-brand-input').value,
            document.getElementById('post-type-input').value,
            document.getElementById('post-code-input').value,
            document.getElementById('post-color-input').value,
            document.getElementById('post-quantity-input').value,
            document.getElementById('post-updated-input').value,
            document.getElementById('post-name-input').value,
            document.getElementById('post-location-input').value,
            document.getElementById('post-notes-input').value,
            document.getElementById('post-min-quantity-warning').value
        );


        while (row.firstChild) {
            row.removeChild(row.firstChild);
        }

        addPrinter(row, editedPrinter);
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
    addNew.addEventListener('click', addNewPrinter);
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to add a listener every time you open the modal. All the listeners stack up, so when the user clicks on `edit` it will execute all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be adding the event listener inside `openmodal`. Every time you open the modal it adds a new listener to the element, but the old listeners are still there, so they all run.

You should add the listeners just once. `openmodal()` can set a global variable that tells the listener which row was selected.

```
var selectedRow;

function openmodal(option, row) {
    backdropModal.style.display = "block";
    modal.style.display = "block";
    if (option === 'add-new') {
        edit.style.display = 'none';
    }
    selectedRow = row;
}

edit.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var editedPrinter = new Printer(
        document.getElementById('post-brand-input').value,
        document.getElementById('post-type-input').value,
        document.getElementById('post-code-input').value,
        document.getElementById('post-color-input').value,
        document.getElementById('post-quantity-input').value,
        document.getElementById('post-updated-input').value,
        document.getElementById('post-name-input').value,
        document.getElementById('post-location-input').value,
        document.getElementById('post-notes-input').value,
        document.getElementById('post-min-quantity-warning').value
    );

    while (selectedRow.firstChild) {
        selectedRow.removeChild(selectedRow.firstChild);
    }

    addPrinter(selectedRow, editedPrinter);
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
addNew.addEventListener('click', addNewPrinter);
```

Comment: Thank you! I will check this out.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want to do this:

```
addNew.addEventListener('click', function(evtObj){
  addNewPrinter.call(this, evtObj, argument1, argument2);
});
```

Comment: I think his question is about the `edit` listener, not `addNew`.